# JPA: EntityManager delete/update

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

When I call EntityManager's update or remove method, I first need to make the entity managed by calling find(). But it means double trip to database.Am I doing it wrongly or is it the only way?

Comment: `EntityManager` has no method like `update()`. Please be clear with the term usage. Use `EntityManager#getReference()` before deleting an entity whenever possible. A merge operation is a different thing where you pass a detached or unmanaged entity to `EntityManager` to make it a managed entity.

Comment: sorry for using wrong word...its merge.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand you correctly. But if you mean you have to do something like 
`Employee employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1); 
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  em.remove(employee);
  em.getTransaction().commit();`

Then yes, you have to do it like that :)

Answer (score 0):

To use `merge` or `remove` methods of 'EntityManager' you need to pass th entity object  in the parameter.

You can also use `native queries` (`em.createNativeQuery`),  which allows you to execute any request you want.

After all, JPA has  a cache layer to prevent unnecessary requests to go all the way to the DB. When you call `find(id)`, JPA will first try to retrieve it from cache if it is not modified since.

So, don't worry about that

Comment: ...but if it doesn't find one in persistent context then it would fetch it from DB.So if I want delete entity, then call to find would make a DB visit to fetch it and then calling delete() would make another call.If I don't  call find() then delete doesn't do anything. Row still lies there in table.I am using OpenJPA.

Comment: Yes! May be in your case, you need to use `native query`

Comment: Try using `entityManager.flush();` to force  synchronize your persistentContext whith DB